# Jquery validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a view to create a DocumentTemplate

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="HexsolveMVC.Helpers" %>

    Create

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#reset").click(function(event) {
            $("#Part").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            $("#txtDocTitle").val("");
            $("#txtarDocDesc").val("");
        });

    });
});
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="main_content">
            <div>
                <%=Html.BreadCrumb(Model.BreadCrumbs)%>
            </div>
            <div class="form_container">
                <h1>
                    Document Template</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <span class="mandatory">*</span>Engine model:</label>
                        <%=Html.DropDownList("Part", (SelectList)ViewData["Part"])%>
                        <span class="tagline">Please select the engine model
                            <%--<a href="#">Need Help</a>--%></span> </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <span class="mandatory">*</span>Document Title:</label>
                        <input id="txtDocTitle" name="docTitle" type="text" class="formstyle" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Discription:</label>
                        <textarea name="docDesc" id="txtarDocDesc" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="button_panel">
                            <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn_create_doc_big" id="button" value="Create" />
                            <span class="reset_field"><a href="#" id="reset">Reset the form</a></span><span class="mandatory_tag">[
                                <span class="mandatory">*</span> Mandatory fields ]</span>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="tagline">By clicking on '<span class="tagline_highlight">Create</span>'
                            button your document will be created.<br />
                            And after you can add new instructions and subsections easily.</span></li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        Example of how to work a document
                    </h2>
                    <img alt="" src="../../html/images/diagram.jpg" width="738" height="172" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to validate the txtDocTitle since its a required field. How can i do this using jQuery. I cannot use Model validation coz this same model is used for other views also and it have properties from other tables. I need something to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery validate

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

You can even set up MVC2 and MVC3 to use it for model validation

http://www.tikalk.com/net/aspnet-mvc-2-client-side-validation-using-jquery-validation-plug